# Joomla setMetada and variables

Tags: php, joomla

We are building a custom component , for seo improve, and we are working now with joomla "setMetaData" function Docs -> [here](https://docs.joomla.org/JDocument/setMetaData)

The normal sintaxis is:

```
$doc->setMetaData( 'tag-name', 'tag-content' );
```

But we need to put a variable in "tag-content" , we use this code, but doesn´t work:

```
$doc->setMetaData( 'DC.Title', echo($params->get('page_description')) );
```

And this doesn´t work as previus:

```
$doc->setMetaData( 'DC.Title', $title );
```

Also we now that "tag-content" only accepts Strings, any idea to solve this?

Thanks for the help and you time.

Comment: Show us where `$title` is defined. Have you defined `$param`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to `echo` it. It is function parameter.

Use this:

```
$doc->setMetaData( 'DC.Title', $doc->getDescription() );
```

Comment: You could try with `$doc->getDescription()`. Edited my answer. Also, where are you setting metadata? Could you show some more code?

Answer (score 0):

First, did you get the $doc object using?

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
```

You don't need to echo the get function for $params.The following should work assuming that the $params object is initialized and not empty.
You can also pass a default value to the get function for testing:

```
$doc->setMetaData( 'DC.Title', $params->get('page_description' , 'defaultValue') );
```

This will return 'defaultValue' if 'page_description' is empty.